# Why are settings.settings variables not updating when I assign to them?

Tags: c#

I have a string variable `username` in `settings.settings` of a C# visual studio winforms app. When I assign to them using normal variable assignment, they don't save. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Properties.Settings.Default.Save()`.

Comment: thanks! This was super helpful and I'll look on google next time.